# Grok pattern for data separated by pipe

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a logfile in which the data is separated by a pipe symbol. "|". An example is below. Does anyone know how to write a GROK pattern to extract it for logstash?

2014-01-07 11:58:48.7694|LOGLEVEL|LOGSOURCE|LOGMESSAGE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [gsub](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.2/filters/mutate#gsub) API to change the pipe "|" to space and the use GROK to extract it.

For example:

```
filter {
    grok {
            match => ["message","%{DATESTAMP:time}\|%{WORD:LOGLEVEL}\|%{WORD:LOGSOURCE}\|%{WORD:LOGMESSAGE}"]
    }
}
```

The above configuration is worked on me with your log. Hope this can help you.

Comment: grok {
            match => ["message","%{DATESTAMP:time}\|%{WORD:LOGLEVEL}\|%{WORD:LOGSOURCE}\|%{WORD:LOGMESSAGE}"]
    }  This also will work, it worked for me

Comment: @ArulT, your comment has more upvotes than the answer, can you please change it to a proper answer?

Answer (score 6):

use this filter:

it works for me. use this site to verify grok patern, https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

```
(?<date>(([0-9]+)-*)+ ([0-9]+:*)+.*)\|%{WORD:LOGLEVEL}\|%{WORD:LOGSOURCE}\|%{WORD:LOGMESSAGE}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
grok { match => ["message","%{DATESTAMP:time}\|%{WORD:LOGLEVEL}\|%{WORD:LOGSOURCE}\|%{WORD:LOGMESSAGE}"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

The LOGMESSAGE part can contain a long content. For this reason, I recommend the following usage.

%{GREEDYDATA:LOGMESSAGE}

Comment: Use http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).